# How to find uncommented public methods using Resharper

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, resharper, resharper-7.1

I am using Resharper 7.1 with Visual Studio 2010. Is there a way to find all uncommented (without method summary and parameter descriptions) public methods through the entire solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need Resharper for this.

Simply check "Generate XML documentation file" in the build tab in project properties, and the compiler will warn you about every missing comment.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is it possible to limit only to public methods?

Comment: @itsbalur: It will warn about all public members. As opposed to type & properties? No.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with the [Agent Smith plugin for ReSharper](https://code.google.com/p/agentsmithplugin/). I wrote about how to do it a long time ago in my blog, but honestly I don't know if this method still works. You can read about it here: http://hmemcpy.com/2010/11/documenting-your-public-api-easily-with-resharper-and-ghostdoc/

Looks like there's a version of Agent Smith plugin [available for ReSharper 7.1](https://code.google.com/p/agentsmithplugin/downloads/list), so you might be in luck!

Comment: The latest version of the Agent Smith plugin is available in the [ReSharper Gallery](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/ReSharper.AgentSmith/)